# Avoiding unchecked casting using generics

Tags: java, generics

I wanted to learn something more about generics and to do so I decided to write a simple application. It allows to retrieve list of all entities using `CriteriaQuery`.

First of all, I tried to generify code by using `type parameter` (**T**). However, my code will not even compile. Why?

```
private static <T> List<T> retrieveAllT(Session session, 
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, T t) {
        CriteriaQuery<t> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(t);
        Root root = query.from(t);
        query.select(root);
        return session.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    }
```

I've come up with another solution. It works fine, but the compiler informs me about unchecked casting. **I understand the reason of that but I'd like to know whether is possible to write this piece of code in a more elegant way (i.e. without unchecked casting)? If so, how do I do that?**

```
private static List<?> retrieveAll(Session session,
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder, Class clazz) {
        CriteriaQuery query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(clazz);
        Root root = query.from(clazz);
        query.select(root);
        return session.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    }
```

To be sure, I am aware of `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

Comment: +1 for asking a question like this rather than blindly throwing a `@SuppressWarnings` on. Too many people want to ignore warnings these days.

Comment: The CriteryaQuery should be <T> from type not <t> from object

Comment: `Root` is a generic interface too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First of all, I tried to generify code by using type parameter (T). However, my code will not even compile. Why?

You are not allowed to parameterize a type with an instance of a class, but must use the type itself:

```
CriteriaQuery<t> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(t);
```

Needs to be changed to:

```
CriteriaQuery<T> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(t);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. When I changed the line, I got the following compilation error: `Error:(76, 49) java: method createQuery in interface javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.Class<T>
  found: T
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) T
    (argument mismatch; T cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<T>)`

Comment: Your `createQuery` method expects a `Class<T>` but you're passing it a `T`.

Comment: I don't think I follow. Could you please incorporate more information in your answer, please? I checked many options yet the code still won't compile when I use `CriteriaQuery<T> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Class<T>)` and `Root<T> root = query.from(Class<T>)`. The error reads `incorrect expression`.

Comment: `createQuery` expects a `Class<T>`, so instead of passing a `T` to `retrieveAllT`, you should pass a `Class<T>` (like you are in your second snippet already, except you need to parameterize it as `Class<T>` instead of `Class`).

Comment: Great. It finally works fine. What page or book would you sugesst om generics? Even thought I've read a lot on this topic yet I couldn't write correct code.

Comment: The only material I've read on Java so far was the study guides for the Java SE 8 certifications, but I've heard a lot of good things about Effective Java.

Comment: @menteith By far the best manual for generics I’ve ever read was [the one by Gilad Bracha](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html).  It taught me everything I know and made generics very clear for me.  You may also want to look at [the official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

Comment: @JacobG. both the lines are the same.